# glFramebufferTexture2D on webgl2 with mipmaps levels

Tags: webgl, webgl2

With webGL2 derived from ES3.0 I thought that we can use **mipmap levels** as the last parameter of:

```
void glFramebufferTexture2D(GLenum target,
GLenum attachment,
GLenum textarget,
GLuint texture,
GLint level);
```

Now from [Khronos ES3.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glFramebufferTexture2D.xhtml) official documentation states that mipmap levels are supposed to work:

> level:
>   Specifies the mipmap level of texture to attach.

From [Khronos ES2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml) instead it says it *must* be 0

> level:
>   Specifies the mipmap level of the texture image to be attached, which must be 0.

Now, the I cannot find any docs from WebGL2.0 context about glFramebufferTexture2D, but the mozilla docs states that mipmap layer must be 0, as in ES2.0, here:
[Mozilla WebGL doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/framebufferTexture2D)

> level:
>   A GLint specifying the mipmap level of the texture image to be attached. Must be 0.

That page I think refers to WebGL1 context but it has mentions of WebGL2 features in it, and I cannot find glFramebufferTexture2D on WebGL2 docs.

So to wrap it up, is there a way to use **mipmap levels** on framebuffer targets on **WebGL2.0**?

(I've looked into layered images but AFAIK layered rendering is not available for WebGL2.0)

Comment: The WebGL2 spec says to see the OpenGL ES 3.0 spec for all details and then lists the few changes from that spec so the docs for WebGL2 are the OpenGL ES 3.0 specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to use mipmap levels on framebuffer targets on WebGL2.0

Yes

I'd close the answer there but I guess I wonder did you actually try something and have it not work? You have to create a WebGL2 context to use mipmap levels as framebuffer attachments but otherwise yes, it works. On WebGL1 it will not work.

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  
  const vs = `#version 300 es
  void main() {
    // just draw an 8x8 pixel point in the center of the target
    // this shader needs/uses no attributes
    gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 8.0;
  }
  `;
  const fsColor = `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
  out vec4 outColor;
  void main() {
    outColor = color;
  }
  `;
  const fsTexture = `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  out vec4 outColor;
  void main() {
    // this shader needs no texcoords since we just
    // use gl_PoitnCoord provided by rendering a point with gl.POINTS
    // bias lets select the mip level so no need for 
    // some fancier shader just to show that it's working.        
    float bias = gl_PointCoord.x * gl_PointCoord.y * 4.0;
    outColor = texture(tex, gl_PointCoord.xy, bias);
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shaders, link into programs, look up attrib/uniform locations
  const colorProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsColor]);
  const textureProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsTexture]);
  
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  const levels = 4;
  const width = 8;
  const height = 8;
  gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, levels, gl.RGBA8, width, height);
  
  // make a framebuffer for each mip level
  const fbs = [];
  for (let level = 0; level < levels; ++level) {
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    fbs.push(fb);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(
        gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, level);
  }
  
  // render a different color to each level
  const colors = [
    [1, 0, 0, 1],  // red
    [0, 1, 0, 1],  // green
    [0, 0, 1, 1],  // blue
    [1, 1, 0, 1],  // yellow
  ];
  gl.useProgram(colorProgramInfo.program);
  for (let level = 0; level < levels; ++level) {
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbs[level]);
    const size = width >> level;
    gl.viewport(0, 0, size, size);
    twgl.setUniforms(colorProgramInfo, { color: colors[level] });
    const offset = 0;
    const count = 1;
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, offset, count);  // draw 1 point
  }
  
  // draw the texture's mips to the canvas
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.useProgram(textureProgramInfo.program);
  // no need to bind the texture it's already bound
  // no need to set the uniform it defaults to 0
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINT, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="8" height="8" style="width: 128px; height: 128px;"></canvas>
```

You can also render to layers of TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY texture.

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  
  const vs = `#version 300 es
  void main() {
    // just draw an 8x8 pixel point in the center of the target
    // this shader needs/uses no attributes
    gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 8.0;
  }
  `;
  const fsColor = `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
  out vec4 outColor;
  void main() {
    outColor = color;
  }
  `;
  const fsTexture = `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  uniform mediump sampler2DArray tex;
  out vec4 outColor;
  void main() {
    // this shader needs no texcoords since we just
    // use gl_PoitnCoord provided by rendering a point with gl.POINTS
    float layer = gl_PointCoord.x * gl_PointCoord.y * 4.0;
    outColor = texture(tex, vec3(gl_PointCoord.xy, layer));
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shaders, link into programs, look up attrib/uniform locations
  const colorProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsColor]);
  const textureProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsTexture]);
  
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tex);
  const levels = 1;
  const width = 8;
  const height = 8;
  const layers = 4;
  gl.texStorage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, levels, gl.RGBA8, width, height, layers);
  // only use level 0 (of course we could render to levels in layers as well)
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  
  // make a framebuffer for each layer
  const fbs = [];
  for (let layer = 0; layer < layers; ++layer) {
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    fbs.push(fb);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    const level = 0;  
    gl.framebufferTextureLayer(
        gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        tex, level, layer);
  }
  
  // render a different color to each layer
  const colors = [
    [1, 0, 0, 1],  // red
    [0, 1, 0, 1],  // green
    [0, 0, 1, 1],  // blue
    [1, 1, 0, 1],  // yellow
  ];
  gl.useProgram(colorProgramInfo.program);
  for (let layer = 0; layer < layers; ++layer) {
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbs[layer]);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
    twgl.setUniforms(colorProgramInfo, { color: colors[layer] });
    const offset = 0;
    const count = 1;
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, offset, count);  // draw 1 point
  }
  
  // draw the texture's mips to the canvas
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.useProgram(textureProgramInfo.program);
  // no need to bind the texture it's already bound
  // no need to set the uniform it defaults to 0
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINT, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="8" height="8" style="width: 128px; height: 128px; image-rendering: pixelated;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to extrapolate a minimal example out of mine code base for another question then, I have a GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION on setting up mipmap levels with glFramebufferTexture2D on cubemaps in webgl2, but I'm also using emscripten so bridging from a desktop/native c++ openGL implementation through their JS to get to webGL2 so I really wasn't sure what/where was the actual problem. If I can get that minimal example I'll fire off another question but this question it's clearly been answered correctly for me!